# Can't receive user locale in the service

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, locale

I have two property files for i18n and want to receive localized message in service method. I've injected `messageSource` and now all I want is to obtain user's locale.

1. First, I tried to do this over `LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()` but it returns my system locale regardless of the request locale.
2. Then I've injected `HttpServletRequest` into service and tried this: `RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request).resolveLocale(request)`, but didn't even receive `LocaleResolver` (it was null).

I can't send locale someway from controller to this service, because it's just implementation of Spring Security's `UserDetailsService`

And I use `CookieLocaleResolver` in my project, if it matters.

Comment: what dictates the locale you want to use?

Comment: @soulcheck didn't quite understand the question.. I want to display localized message at unsuccessful authorization, so I should know current user locale

Comment: in that case the locale is determined by the request. You can obtain it in your controller/authentication interceptor and pass it to the service as a parameter.

Comment: are you displaying the error message as part of a jsp?

Comment: yes, I'm displaying `${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}`. so isn't it enough to inject request to the service, if locale is stored in request?

Comment: no, injection works before any request is made.

Comment: @soulcheck Thank you! I now know the direction in which to move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you want to leave presentation problems to the presentation layer.

In your case, since you want to display the message in the jsp, use `<spring:message />` (or plain `<fmt:message />`) tag in that jsp and let spring worry about the l10n.

If you can't do that, another option is throwing an exception from your service layer and handling it in controller/interceptor where you have access to `ServletRequest` and, in consequence, to the user's locale.

Comment: Of course, I'm using `<spring:message/>` in my project. But, as I understand, in general case during the authorization may occur different errors, which I want translate and give to Spring Security. How can I solve this nuance using `<spring:message/>`?

Comment: @vasileusky well of course there are different classes of errors that can happen, but only authentication error is authentication specific and, at least in spring-security, you can define an error page for that using `<security:access-denied-handler />`

Comment: Thank you for help! I'll try to throw exception in my service and handle it somewhere on a higher level.